# BigDecimal HALF_UP rounding issue

Tags: java, math, rounding, bigdecimal

I am trying to round 0.14049 using scale=3 and HALF_UP rounding mode and hoping to see rounded value = 0.141 but getting 0.140 instead.

As per my understanding the last decimal digit 9 should round up the 4 to 5 and that should in-turn round up 0 to 1 when using scale 3 and i should see 0.141.

Is that a bug in BigDecimal setScale method or my expectation of Rounding is wrong. How can I get rounded values similar to 0.141 and not 0.140?

```
BigDecimal bd=new BigDecimal("0.14049");
BigDecimal normalizedField = field.setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(normalizedField);
// Output = 0.140
```

Comment: Your value would need to be at least 0.1405 for HALF_UP to take effect

Comment: 1.14049 is closer to 1.140 than 1.141.  Why do you expect rounding to take you to the further-away value?  Your expectation is wrong, not BigDecimal.

Comment: thanks for the example, i was misled by some existing implementation in our codebase.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> As per my understanding the last decimal digit 9 should round up the 4 to 5 and that should in-turn round up 0 to 1 when using scale 3 and i should see 0.141.

This understanding is incorrect. Rounding is not an iterative process. Only the first digit after the scale position is considered, not the whole chain of digits. In your case, the digit is 4, so it gets converted down to zero.

Comment: thank for clarifying, i was under assumption that it starts from least significant digit and starts rounding and the results carry over towards the more significant decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your business domain, the "4999998" case will happen always on the same position. I had a similar situation, were the scale was 2. So I added and extra step to the rounding. In your case:

```
BigDecimal bd=new BigDecimal("0.14049");
BigDecimal normalizedField = bd.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(normalizedField);
```